# Second-order Differential Equation - Kirchoff's Law

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Study of a closed electrical circuit by Kirchhoff's current law. Denote voltage by $v$, current by $j$, and non-negative values of resistor, inductor and capacitor by $R$; $L$; $C$. The equations are
> $\frac{dv}{dt}=jC$ and $\frac{dj}{dt}=-\frac RLj-\frac vL$.

> (i) Rewrite the above system by setting $x_1 = v$; $x_2 = \frac{dv}{dt} = \frac jC$; $w^2=\frac1{LC}$; $2k=\frac RL$:

> Then convert the first-order system into the linear second-order equation for $v$ such that

> $$\frac{d^2v}{dt^2}+2k\frac{dv}{dt}+w^2v=0$$

> (ii) Let $k = 0$ in above, given $v(0) = v_0 > 0$, and $j(0) = 0$. Find the time at which the current $j(t)$ begins to change its sign. Describe the geometry of the phase diagrams in this case.

**My Solutions:**

(i) I know roughly what to do although am confused about which variables it wants the first-order system in but can make the second-order ODE.

(ii) If $k=0$, this gives

$$\frac{d^2v}{dt^2}+w^2v=0$$

which gives the general solution of $v(t)=A\cos(wt)+B\sin(wt)$. Subbing in the initial conditions I get $v(t)=v_0\cos(wt)$ and so $\frac{dv}{dt}=-wv_0\sin(wt)$. This means $j(t)=-Cwv_0\sin(wt)$.

Then to find when $j(t)$ changes sign, can see that its equation is just an enlargement of the sin graph and so will first change sign when $j(t)=0$, i.e. when $t=\frac\pi w$. [However, I'm not sure if this is a valid answer and whether there's a better way of doing it?]

Comment: Please use MathJax, it is painful to decipher the above.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, you substitute $x_1=v$ and $x_2=\frac{dv}{dt}$ so that

$$\frac{d^2v}{dt^2}+2k\frac{dv}{dt}+w^2v=0\iff\frac{dx_2}{dt}+2kx_2+w^2x_1=0$$

and

$$\frac{dx_1}{dt}=\frac{dv}{dt}=x_2$$

So the system (in matrix form) is

$$\frac d{dt}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-w^2&-2k\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix}$$

Your approach for the second part seems fine, though take care to make sure the sign indeed changes to the left or right of wherever $j(t)=0$. (For instance, $j(t)=t^2$ is non-negative for all $t$, despite $j(0)=0$.)